# Problem with Gridview and objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
           SelectMethod="GetObjects" TypeName="ControlPanelMessages">
       </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

What i need is to put two items into one row.. The Img and the Name should be in the same row.

How do I achieve that?

Update..can I do this:

DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();

```
// Set values in the columns:
newRow["Img"] = "NewCompanyImage";
newRow["Img"] = "NewCompanyName";
```

will it put both values in the same row?

Thats what i did:

```
    public DataSet GetObjects()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var source = from p in CommentsList
                 select new { p.Img, p.Name, p.Comment };
    dt.Columns.Add("User");
    dt.Columns.Add("Comment");

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        DataRow UserDetailsRow=dt.NewRow();
        UserDetailsRow["User"] = item.Img;
        UserDetailsRow["User"] = item.Name;
        UserDetailsRow["Comment"] = item.Comment;
      //  dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { item.Img, item.Name, item.Comment });
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    return ds;
}
```

Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added any columns to the data table yet, you'll need to do

```
dt.Columns.Add("Img");
```

for each column you want in there before you add a row.

Comment: Nope, you'd have to do UserDetailsRow["User"] = item.Img + " " + item.Name; or something similar.